# Patch Package with Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, patch-package

I'm working with a node js backend and I want to deploy the application via docker.

I changed two npm packages to get my application working and automatically install these changes with npm patch-package with the help of a post install script in my package.json.

```
 "postinstall": "patch-package"
```

I installed both both postinstall-postinstall and patch-package as dev dependencies.

Running yarn install and yarn build seperatly this works fine but once I want to dockerize this application I get an error during the build phase, which basically says that the patch wasn't applied to the node_modules.

This is my dockerfile:

```
# stage 1
FROM node as builder
WORKDIR /srv
COPY package.json yarn.lock patches ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --unsafe-perm
COPY . .
RUN yarn build
```

I don't really know if the yarn install script in the dockerfile is not running post install or if the error only happens in the yarn build script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you confirm if the patch file is being successfully copied into your container where you want it to be?

Comment: Found my error. I copied the patches directory into the root directory of the docker image and not into a separate patches directory

Answer (score 4):

As @donjus mentioned in the comments, the patches were being copied to the root directory, not inside of `patches`.

The solution is to change:

```
COPY package.json yarn.lock patches ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --unsafe-perm
```

to

```
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
COPY ./patches ./patches
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --unsafe-perm
```